# How often are new Macbooks released?

Tags: macbook

How often are new Macbooks released? And, does anyone know when they were last released?

Comment: I think this is OK because it's definitely hardware related -- and buying Apple hardware is an art, because you get totally boned if you buy at the wrong time.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check out these sites:

- [Apple Buyer's Guide (model ordered)](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/)
- [Apple Buyer's Guide (time ordered)](http://tinyurl.com/35nodg)

They keep track of **how often Apple's products are released**, and **how long it has been since their last release**. They use this information to recommend whether you should **buy now or wait**.

[Direct link to the section about MacBooks.](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#Portable_Macs)

As of 1-16-10:

- The latest MacBook was released **88** days ago, and is updated every **194** days on average.
- The latest MacBook Pro was released **222** days ago, and is updated every **200** days on average.
- The latest MacBook Air was released **222** days ago, and is updated every **255** days on average.

Comment: Wow! That's EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They change them all the time. I believe the last release date was in September, which is usually when Apple finishes up its winter product line-up.

If something is released, it will be Janurary 26th (?). That is the date of the next Apple Conference. Although most people are predicting the release of the Apple Tablet.

When Apple releases/refreshes products is pretty predictable. There are 3 major conferences through the year. January 26th, June Somethingth, and September 9th.

Given, they don't always release/refresh a new product at each one of those conferences, but if something 'will' happen, it will be at one of those dates.

Answer (score 1):

The timeframe varies but usually they renew the Macbook series every two years or so, I believe in January when Apple holds their yearly conference in San Francisco.  However, there have been big changes the last two years running, including upgrading all Macbooks to Macbook Pros with more RAM, etc.